# Mysql restore to restore structure and no data from a given backup (schema.sql)

Tags: mysql, database, restore

Hi I use mysql administrator and have restored backup files (backup.sql).  I would like to use restore the structure without data and it is not giving me an option to do so.  I understand phpadmin provides this.  I can not use this however.  Any one can tell me an easy way?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  My first attempt was that, but the insert statements are listed after each table, and there are over 100 tables.function is not integrated in mysql administrator restore function.  I have no control over the method of back up.  I am looking for a more automated way.  Also please note I can not imagine this

Answer (score 6):

Dump database structure only:

`cat backup.sql | grep -v ^INSERT | mysql -u $USER -p`

This will execute everything in the backup.sql file except the INSERT lines that would have populated the tables. After running this you should have your full table structure along with any stored procedures / views / etc. that were in the original databse, but your tables will all be empty.

Comment: I used `cat backup.sql | grep -v ^INSERT | mysql -u$USER -p$PASSWORD database` which worked for me fine.

Comment: `cat backup.sql | grep -v ^INSERT | grep -v ^"      ("` worked for me because my inserts were not in just one line.

Comment: nice. I sent my output to a file like this: cat backup.sql | grep -v ^INSERT > schema.sql so I could review first. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the ENGINE to BLACKHOLE in the dump using sed

```
cat backup.sql | sed 's/ENGINE=(MYISAM|INNODB)/ENGINE=BLACKHOLE/g' > backup2.sql
```

This engine will just "swallow" the INSERT statements and the tables will remain empty. Of course you must change the ENGINE again using:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the backup.sql files (if created by mysqldump) are just SQL commands in a text file. Just copy-paste all the "create ..." statements from the beginning of the file, but not the "insert" statements in to another file and "mysql < newfile" you should have the empty database without any data in it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to tell the mysql client to skip the INSERT commands. the least-hassle way to do this is run the script as-is and let it load the data, then just TRUNCATE all of the tables.

Comment: Thank you all.  It seems like, there is no other way but to manually truncate each table after restoring it.

Comment: I forgot to add that there are constraints on many tables avoiding any truncate on those tables.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a script to do the following:

1 : import the dump into a new database.

2 : truncate all the tables with a loop.

3 : export the db again.

4 : now u just have the structure

Answer (score -1):

You can backup you MYSQL database structure with

```
mysqldump -u username –p  -d database_name > backup.sql
```

(You should not supply password at command line as it leads to security risks.MYSQL will ask for password by default.)

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question. OP only wants the schema. Your answer dumps schema and data, and says nothing about restore.